# Why does ReSharper tell me "implicitly captured closure"?

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

I have the following code:

```
public double CalculateDailyProjectPullForceMax(DateTime date, string start = null, string end = null)
{
    Log("Calculating Daily Pull Force Max...");

    var pullForceList = start == null
                             ? _pullForce.Where((t, i) => _date[i] == date).ToList() // implicitly captured closure: end, start
                             : _pullForce.Where(
                                 (t, i) => _date[i] == date && DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(start)) > 0 && 
                                           DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(end)) < 0).ToList();

    _pullForceDailyMax = Math.Round(pullForceList.Max(), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    return _pullForceDailyMax;
}
```

Now, I've added a comment on the line that [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) is suggesting a change. What does it mean, or why would it need to be changed? `implicitly captured closure: end, start`

Comment: MyCodeSucks please fix the accepted answer: kevingessner's one is wrong (as explained in the comments) and having it marked as accepted will mislead users if they don't notice Console's answer.

Comment: You may also see this if you define your list outside of a try/catch and do all your adding in the try/catch and then set the results to another object. Moving the defining/adding within the try/catch will allow GC. Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

The warning tells you that the variables `end` and `start` stay alive as any of the lambdas inside this method stay alive.

Take a look at the short example

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    int i = 0;
    Random g = new Random();
    this.button1.Click += (sender, args) => this.label1.Text = i++.ToString();
    this.button2.Click += (sender, args) => this.label1.Text = (g.Next() + i).ToString();
}
```

I get an "Implicitly captured closure: g" warning at the first lambda. It is telling me that `g` cannot be [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) as long as the first lambda is in use.

The compiler generates a class for both lambda expressions and puts all variables in that class which are used in the lambda expressions.

So in my example `g` and `i` are held in the same class for execution of my delegates. If `g` is a heavy object with a lot of resources left behind, the garbage collector couldn't reclaim it, because the reference in this class is still alive as long as any of the lambda expressions is in use. So this is a potential memory leak, and that is the reason for the R# warning.

@splintor
As in C# the anonymous methods are always stored in one class per method there are two ways to avoid this:

1. Use an instance method instead of an anonymous one.
2. Split the creation of the lambda expressions into two methods.

Comment: What are possible ways to avoid this capture?

Comment: Thanks for this great answer - I've learned that there is a reason to use non-anonymous method even if it's used in just one place.

Comment: @splintor Instantiate the object inside the delegate, or pass it as a parameter instead.  In the case above, as far as I can tell, the desired behavior is actually to hold a reference to the `Random` instance, though.

Comment: @ScottRhee I mean, in that case you just end up making it a private instance field, right?  If you actually need to hold on to an instance of something changing it to a separate method won't really change anything significant.

Comment: @emodendroket Correct, at this point we're talking code style and readability.  A field is easier to reason about.  If memory pressure or object lifetimes are important I'd chose the field, otherwise I'd leave it in the more concise closure.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this anti-feature and get the expected behavior of one generated class per lambda?

Comment: @dlf no there is no way of getting that behavior. Most of the time I come accross this warning, the design of the class is bad, not the "compiler magic" that deals with it.

Comment: My case (heavily) simplified boiled down to a factory method that creates a Foo and a Bar. It then subscribes capturing lambas to events exposed by those two objects and, surprise surprise, the Foo keeps the captures from the Bar event's lamba alive and vice-versa. I come from C++ where this approach would have worked just fine, and was more than a little astonished to find the rules were different here. The more you know, I guess.

Answer (score 36):

Agreed with Peter Mortensen.

The C# compiler generates only one type that encapsulates all variables for all lambda expressions in a method.

For example, given the source code:

```
public class ValueStore
{
    public Object GetValue()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public void SetValue(Object obj)
    {
    }
}

public class ImplicitCaptureClosure
{
    public void Captured()
    {
        var x = new object();

        ValueStore store = new ValueStore();
        Action action = () => store.SetValue(x);
        Func<Object> f = () => store.GetValue();    //Implicitly capture closure: x
    }
}
```

The compiler generates a type looks like :

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class c__DisplayClass2
{
  public object x;
  public ValueStore store;

  public c__DisplayClass2()
  {
    base.ctor();
  }

  //Represents the first lambda expression: () => store.SetValue(x)
  public void Capturedb__0()
  {
    this.store.SetValue(this.x);
  }

  //Represents the second lambda expression: () => store.GetValue()
  public object Capturedb__1()
  {
    return this.store.GetValue();
  }
}
```

And the `Capture` method is compiled as:

```
public void Captured()
{
  ImplicitCaptureClosure.c__DisplayClass2 cDisplayClass2 = new ImplicitCaptureClosure.c__DisplayClass2();
  cDisplayClass2.x = new object();
  cDisplayClass2.store = new ValueStore();
  Action action = new Action((object) cDisplayClass2, __methodptr(Capturedb__0));
  Func<object> func = new Func<object>((object) cDisplayClass2, __methodptr(Capturedb__1));
}
```

Though the second lambda does not use `x`, it cannot be garbage collected as `x` is compiled as a  property of the generated class used in the lambda.

Answer (score 31):

The warning is valid and displayed in methods that have *more than one lambda*, and they *capture different values*.

When a method that contains lambdas is invoked, a compiler-generated object is instantiated with:

- instance methods representing the lambdas
- fields representing all values captured by *any* of those lambdas

As an example:

```
class DecompileMe
{
    DecompileMe(Action<Action> callable1, Action<Action> callable2)
    {
        var p1 = 1;
        var p2 = "hello";

        callable1(() => p1++);    // WARNING: Implicitly captured closure: p2

        callable2(() => { p2.ToString(); p1++; });
    }
}
```

Examine the generated code for this class (tidied up a little):

```
class DecompileMe
{
    DecompileMe(Action<Action> callable1, Action<Action> callable2)
    {
        var helper = new LambdaHelper();

        helper.p1 = 1;
        helper.p2 = "hello";

        callable1(helper.Lambda1);
        callable2(helper.Lambda2);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class LambdaHelper
    {
        public int p1;
        public string p2;

        public void Lambda1() { ++p1; }

        public void Lambda2() { p2.ToString(); ++p1; }
    }
}
```

Note the instance of `LambdaHelper` created stores both `p1` and `p2`.

Imagine that:

- `callable1` keeps a long-lived reference to its argument, `helper.Lambda1`
- `callable2` does not keep a reference to its argument, `helper.Lambda2`

In this situation, the reference to `helper.Lambda1` also indirectly references the string in `p2`, and this means that the garbage collector will not be able to deallocate it. At worst it is a memory/resource leak. Alternatively it may keep object(s) alive longer than otherwise needed, which can have an impact on GC if they get promoted from gen0 to gen1.

Comment: if we took out the reference of `p1` from `callable2` like this: `callable2(() => { p2.ToString(); });` - would this still not cause the same issue (garbage collector will not be able to deallocate it) as `LambdaHelper` will still contain `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: Yes, the same problem would exist. The compiler creates one capture object (i.e. `LambdaHelper` above) for all lambdas within the parent method. So even if `callable2` made no use of `p1`, it would share the same capture object as `callable1`, and that capture object would reference both `p1` and `p2`. Note that this only really matters for reference types, and `p1` in this example is a value type.

Answer (score 3):

For Linq to Sql queries, you may get this warning. The lambda's scope may outlive the method due to the fact that the query is often actualized after the method is out of scope. Depending on your situation, you may want to actualize the results (i.e. via .ToList()) within the method to allow for GC on the method's instance vars captured in the L2S lambda.

Answer (score 3):

### You could always figure out with a reasons of R# suggestions just by clicking on the hints like shown below:

[image]

This hint will direct you [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/ImplicitlyCapturedClosure.html).

---

> This inspection draws your attention to the fact that more closure
>   values are being captured than is obviously visibly, which has an
>   impact on the lifetime of these values.
>
> Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> using System; 
> public class Class1 {
>     private Action _someAction;
>
>     public void Method() {
>         var obj1 = new object();
>         var obj2 = new object();
>
>         _someAction += () => {
>             Console.WriteLine(obj1);
>             Console.WriteLine(obj2);
>         };
>
>         // "Implicitly captured closure: obj2"
>         _someAction += () => {
>             Console.WriteLine(obj1);
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In the first closure, we see that both obj1 and obj2 are being explicitly captured; we can see this just by looking at the code. For
>   the second closure, we can see that obj1 is being explicitly captured,
>   but ReSharper is warning us that obj2 is being implicitly captured.
>
> This is due to an implementation detail in the C# compiler. During
>   compilation, closures are rewritten into classes with fields that hold
>   the captured values, and methods that represent the closure itself.
>   The C# compiler will only create one such private class per method,
>   and if more than one closure is defined in a method, then this class
>   will contain multiple methods, one for each closure, and it will also
>   include all captured values from all closures.
>
> If we look at the code that the compiler generates, it looks a little
>   like this (some names have been cleaned up to ease reading):
>
> ```
> public class Class1 {
>     [CompilerGenerated]
>     private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1_0
>     {
>         public object obj1;
>         public object obj2;
>
>         internal void <Method>b__0()
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(obj1);
>             Console.WriteLine(obj2);
>         }
>
>         internal void <Method>b__1()
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(obj1);
>         }
>     }
>
>     private Action _someAction;
>
>     public void Method()
>     {
>         // Create the display class - just one class for both closures
>         var dc = new Class1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0();
>
>         // Capture the closure values as fields on the display class
>         dc.obj1 = new object();
>         dc.obj2 = new object();
>
>         // Add the display class methods as closure values
>         _someAction += new Action(dc.<Method>b__0);
>         _someAction += new Action(dc.<Method>b__1);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> When the method runs, it creates the display class, which captures all values, for all closures. So even if a value isn't used
>   in one of the closures, it will still be captured. This is the
>   "implicit" capture that ReSharper is highlighting.
>
> The implication of this inspection is that the implicitly captured
>   closure value will not be garbage collected until the closure itself
>   is garbage collected. The lifetime of this value is now tied to the
>   lifetime of a closure that does not explicitly use the value. If the
>   closure is long lived, this might have a negative effect on your code,
>   especially if the captured value is very large.
>
> Note that while this is an implementation detail of the compiler, it
>   is consistent across versions and implementations such as Microsoft
>   (pre and post Roslyn) or Mono's compiler. The implementation must work
>   as described in order to correctly handle multiple closures capturing
>   a value type. For example, if multiple closures capture an int, then
>   they must capture the same instance, which can only happen with a
>   single shared private nested class. The side effect of this is that
>   the lifetime of all captured values is now the maximum lifetime of any
>   closure that captures any of the values.