# Synchronize collections: ReSharper "Implicitly captured closure"

Tags: c#, collections, closures, resharper

I implemented this extension method to synchronize a collection from another that can be of different type:

```
public static void Synchronize<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this ICollection<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool> match,
    Func<TSecond, TFirst> create)
{
    var secondCollection = second.ToArray();

    var toAdd = secondCollection.Where(item => !first.Any(x => match(x, item))).Select(create);

    foreach (var item in toAdd)
    {
        first.Add(item);
    }

    var toRemove = first.Where(item => !secondCollection.Any(x => match(item, x))).ToArray();

    foreach (var item in toRemove)
    {
        first.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

ReSharper give me two "Implicitly captured closure", one on the first Where and one on the second, is there a way to fix it? I cannot find one.

**[Update]**

Based on the observation of Eric, I wrote a version that is faster than the one with the equals function, using instead the hash:

```
public static void Synchronize<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this ICollection<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TSecond, TFirst> convert,
    Func<TFirst, int> firstHash = null,
    Func<TSecond, int> secondHash = null)
{
    if (firstHash == null)
    {
        firstHash = x => x.GetHashCode();
    }

    if (secondHash == null)
    {
        secondHash = x => x.GetHashCode();
    }

    var firstCollection = first.ToDictionary(x => firstHash(x), x => x);
    var secondCollection = second.ToDictionary(x => secondHash(x), x => x);

    var toAdd = secondCollection.Where(item => firstCollection.All(x => x.Key != item.Key)).Select(x => convert(x.Value));

    foreach (var item in toAdd)
    {
        first.Add(item);
    }

    var toRemove = firstCollection.Where(item => secondCollection.All(x => x.Key != item.Key));

    foreach (var item in toRemove)
    {
        first.Remove(item.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer some time ago:

[Read more here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633617/why-does-resharper-tell-me-implicitly-captured-closure/15843306#15843306

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First let me characterize the problem that Resharper is attempting to alert you to here. Suppose you have:

```
Action M(Expensive expensive, Cheap cheap)
{
    Action shortLived = ()=>{DoSomething(expensive);};
    DoSomethingElse(shortLived);
    Action longLived = ()=>{DoAnotherThing(cheap);};
    return longLived;
}
```

The issue here is that in C# (and VB, and JScript and many other languages), the lifetime of *both* `cheap` and `expensive` is extended to match the lifetime of *both* `shortLived` and `longLived`.  So what happens is even though `longLived` does not use `expensive`, the expensive resource is never garbage collected until `longLived` dies.

Your program matches this pattern; you make two delegates out of two lambdas; one of them uses `first` and the other does not. Therefore `first` will survive as long as the longer of the two delegates.

Second let me criticize Resharper here. This is clearly a false positive. In order for this to be a true positive *one of the delegates has to be long lived*. In this case both delegates will be eligible for collection when the method returns; both are short lived and therefore there is no actual bug here.  Resharper could track the query objects returned by `Where` and notice that they do not survive the method.

Third, what should you do about it?  I would be inclined to do nothing about it; if the code is working as you like it then keep it working. I would not be concerned about the Resharper warning; I would be far, far more concerned about the fact that your code is *extremely inefficient for large collections*. If the two collections have n and m items then this program does O(nm) operations.

Comment: So Eric, in this case ReSharper "cannot" know if the warning is a false positive and I can ignore it.
Have you a more efficient alternative to my implementation?

Comment: @MatteoMigliore: The expensive part of your implementation is that you're running a matching predicate against all pairs. If you can supply a *hashing* function that is *consistent* with the matching predicate -- that is, two matching elements have the same hash code -- and has *good distribution* of hash values -- then you can build a hash table that is O(1), which will reduce your cost from O(nm) to O(n+m).

Answer (score -1):

Secondcollection variable is used in both the places which is the actual cause. Make the first expression to use variable 'second' instead of secondcollection. Problem is better explained in http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/implicit-closures-in-c-lambdas/

Comment: No, because I even obtain the warning but on the "first" variable and I also obtain the "possible multiple enumeration" on the "second" variable.